# Pinpoint Maritime location with mobile device (Android & iPhone)

Tags: google-maps, mobile, gps, mobile-application

I'm looking to build a mobile app that needs to locate the user maritime position and present it on a map.

My questions is what kind of precision can I expect and if someone has done something similar and what unexpected pitfalls can I encounter.

Also, is there any solution to work around the potential lack of internet connectivity and map loading?

Ideally I'm looking at using the device geolocation with google maps but I've come accross these and I'm not sure if it can give me greater precision:
http://www.navionics.com/en/web-api

Thanks

Comment: Android applications do not use the Google Maps API V3. (tag removed)

Comment: In that case it is not an Android or iPhone app. It is just a web app.